# remove vowels from a sentence but not when its a single char

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to remove the vowels from the sentence.
But it should omit **the single vowel char** like **I** and **a** in between sentences

How to include the single vowel char in the output?

```
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'O', 'U')
    def sms_encoding(data):
        list1=data.split()
        list2=''
        list3=''
        for i in range(0,len(list1)):
            if len(list1[i])==1:
                list2+=(list1[i])

            if len(list1[i])!=1: 
                for char in data:    
                    if char in vowels:
                        data = data.replace(char, '')
                        list3=list2+(data)

        return list3

    data="a Have a nice day"
    print(sms_encoding(data))
```

the output is

> a Hv  nc dy

Comment: Fascinating - do you have a question?

Comment: I need to include the "a" in between "have" and "nice".
how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` to create a `list` where each `element` is a word. You can then use a `generator-expression` to remove the `words` which are `vowels`. We also need to use `str.join` to join the words back together with a space between each one.

This leaves us with a neat one-line solution:

```
def sms_encoding(s):
    return ' '.join(w for w in s.split() if w not in 'aeiou')
```

and a test in the interpreter shows that it works:

```
>>> sms_encoding('a have a nice day')
'have nice day'
```

---

Or, if you want to **keep** the single-character vowels but remove the ones in words, you can use `re.sub`, with [this regex on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cTPXBD/1).

So that would make your function something like:

```
import re
def sms_encoding(s):
    return re.sub('(?<!\s)[aeiou](?!\s)', '', s)
```

which works the other way around when tested:

```
>>> sms_encoding('a have a nice day')
'a hve a nce dy'
```

Comment: @usr2564301 "I need to include the "a" in between "have" and "nice". how do i do that?" - please remove the DV, this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @usr2564301 I agree there is conflict in the question, but I have added the other solution anyway so now you have no excuse not to remove the DV :)